# Spatial join results different in ModelBuilder and right-click join?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-join

I am trying to incorporate a simple spatial join in a model but the spatial join options in ModelBuilder are different from the right click-->join options. How can I do the join as in the image below in the data management-->

[image]

Above process works fine but I have to do it manually.

The process below fails/doesn't give the result I want and I need to incorporate this in the model as otherwise I have to do this manually and then complete the process in a second model.

[image]

Comment: Is this because when you right click join, that is an attribute or common attribute column join. Where as a spatial join is a join based on features from one spatial dataset intersecting feature from a second spatial dataset.  They are different types of joins.

Comment: The right click join has two options at the top, an attribute join and spatial join as per the image in my question.

Comment: Are they both in the same coordinate system. I know in the python runtime there is some coordinate system switching that was happening to me and I wasn't get the expected results.  After I would loop through some spatial intersections I had to re-set the "dataframe" or environment to get accurate results.  Perhaps model builder isn't taking care of some on the fly projecting for you like you think.

Comment: I'd start by reversing your Target and Join Features - you appear to be wanting to join values from your Buffered Tower Range polygons onto your target Signal_Strength_Added points but have the opposite in your Spatial Join dialog.

Comment: What is wrong with the result? It looks like it should be the same join to me. Are you sur"e you don't have "Target Features" and "Join Features the wrong way round in the Toolbox Spatial Join?

Comment: in both it is point fc as the target and the poly fc as the "join" feature. The process just crashes after a while.

Comment: Does it crash with an error message that we can search for?  It may give some clues as to whether you are hitting a geoprocessing limit.  It sounds like you are intersecting many points, each with potentially many overlapping polygons, which may stretch ArcGIS and the resources available to it.  I've not used Spatial Join on large datasets so am not sure how likely that is.  If that is the limit being hit then tiling the data first, which you are looking into elsewhere, is the right way to go.

Comment: yup...I am going to close this question as it is definitely a file size issue. I tried the spatial join in the with a smaller dataset and it worked fine.

Comment: From the screenshot you appear to be wanting to join values from your Buffered Tower Range polygons onto your target Signal_Strength_Added points but have the opposite in your Spatial Join dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was based on the size of the dataset and not any real difference with the tools.

Further info is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612882/split-a-large-text-xyz-database-into-x-equal-parts